# calling php code with ajax results in an error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to call some php code using ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#email_address").on("keypress", function() {
        request = $.ajax({
            url: '../verify_email.php',
            data: {email: $("#email_address").val(),
                   submitted: true},
            type: 'post'
        });

        request.done(function(response) {
            //fooling around to see if this works
            if(response) {
                alert("valid email");
            } else {
                alert("invalid email");
            }
        });

        request.error(function(response) {
            alert("an error occurred");
        });
    });
});
```

However, the request.error function runs. I'm not too sure why. Here is the php code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submitted']) and isset($_POST['email'])) {
        if(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            echo 'true';
        } else {
            echo 'false';
        }
    }
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you have in the response?

Comment: Have a look at the Network tab in Chrome's web inspector (filter XHR), you should get all the info you need from there ;)

Answer (score 1):

ugh, noob mistake. i had set the php url to be relative to the .js file instead of to the web page. it was supposed to be:

```
    request = $.ajax({
        url: 'verify_email.php'
```

instead of

```
    request = $.ajax({
        url: '../verify_email.php',
```

i figured it out with the use of Chrome's web inspector . i learned two new things today: what the url has to be relative to and how to use Chrome's web inspector. thanks all for your help

Comment: Hi @Matt, the return true/false in php file works fine in javascript??

Comment: Hi @Cuchu - thanks for the reminder. That was another problem I had with the code. I didn't realize I had to echo values. I've edited the question to reflect that so as not to confuse people. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your url work fine, in php try to return json ;)

```
<?php
    $return = false;

    if(isset($_POST['submitted']) and isset($_POST['email'])) {
        if(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $return = true;
        } else {
            $return = false;
        }
    }

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('result' => $return));
die;

?>
```

And in javascript try:

```
request.done(function(response) {
            //fooling around to see if this works
            if(response.result) {
                alert("valid email");
            } else {
                alert("invalid email");
            }
        });
```

Comment: nice! i'll give that a shot :)